# primary key changes value after update - becomes 0

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

Well it seems I've found the problem.

Because the values for the fields where automatically produced by taking substrings of the names of an HTML form fields, one of the values was appearing as ***id*** (it can be seen in the echo I've posted bellow). The update as it seems, didn't fail but produced this unexpected behavior.

Thanks to all who tried to help and sorry for the stupid question.

---

After I execute an update statement like

```
UPDATE tablename SET field='value' WHERE field='value'
```

without ever touching my primary key, it change's value from what it was before to 0.

Any ideas?

MySQL Server version: 5.5.37-0+wheezy1

This is the code that generates the query

```
$query2 = "UPDATE student SET ";

            foreach ($_POST as $the_key => $a_post_arg) {
                if (strcmp($the_key, "student_password") === 0) {
                    //without activation
                    $a_post_arg = md5($a_post_arg);

                    //with activation
                    //$a_post_arg = "Not activated!";
                }
                if (strcmp($the_key, "student_registration_year") === 0)
                    $a_post_arg = $a_post_arg . "-00-00";                   
                if (strcmp(substr($the_key, 0, 14), "student_stats_") === 0 || strcmp($the_key, "student_validationImageTextfield") === 0) {
                    $student_stats[$the_key] = $a_post_arg;
                    continue;
                }

                if (strcmp(substr($the_key, 0, 7), "student") === 0 && strcmp($the_key, "student_email_retype") !== 0 && strcmp($the_key, "student_password_retype") !== 0) {                   

                    if (strcmp($the_key, "student_email") !== 0) {
                        if (strcmp($the_key, "student_select_dept") === 0) {
                            $query2 .= "dept='" . addslashes($a_post_arg) . "', ";
                        } else if (strcmp($the_key, "student_semester") === 0) {
                            $query2 .= "studying_semester='" . addslashes($a_post_arg) . "', ";
                        } else if (strcmp($the_key, "student_father_name") === 0) {
                            $query2 .= "fathers_name='" . addslashes($a_post_arg) . "', ";
                        } else if (strcmp($the_key, "student_academic_id") === 0) {
                            $query2 .= "academicIDNumber='" . addslashes($a_post_arg) . "', ";
                        } else {
                            $query2 .= substr($the_key, 8) . "='" . addslashes($a_post_arg) . "', ";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            $query2 .= "status='registered' WHERE email='" . $_POST['student_email'] . "';";
```

This is an echo of $query2. The PK for the table is the auto increment field **id** and the **email** field.

```
query 2 = UPDATE student SET name='Όνομα', surname='Επώνυμο', dob='1970-09-09',
fathers_name='Ονοματεπώνυμο πατέρα', mother_name='Ονοματεπώνυμο μητέρας',
nationality='Υπηκοότητα', adt='Α.Δ.Τ.', password='0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661',
dept='biology', id='Αριθμός μητρώου', studying_semester='6', registration_year='2001-00-00',
atlas_id='1234', academicIDNumber='123456789012', perm_address_road='Οδός', 
perm_address_number='Αριθμός', perm_address_area='Περιοχή/Πόλη', perm_address_PObox='Τ.Κ.', 
perm_address_Country='Χώρα', study_address_road='Οδός', study_address_number='Αριθμός', 
study_address_area='Περιοχή/Πόλη', study_address_PObox='Τ.Κ.', study_address_Country='Χώρα', 
telephone='+305555555555', cellphone='+305555555555', fax='+305555555555', afm='Α.Φ.Μ.', 
eforia='Δ.Ο.Υ.', amka='Α.Μ.Κ.Α.', amika='Α.Μ.ΙΚΑ', status='registered' WHERE email='20@send.com';
```

Comment: It can't happen from that statement by itself, there must be more going on in your application.

Comment: Are you really setting the field to the same value as in the `WHERE` clause? That won't do anything.

Comment: What does the actual query look like?

Comment: I guess you missed set cuotes on set statement, so values value is zero. Show PHP code

Comment: @Horaciux: it's not possible either

Comment: Do you have any `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger on this table?

Comment: Please post `SHOW CREATE TABLE student`.  Interested to see if your PK column has a `DEFAULT` value.

Comment: @Horaciux Triple equals basically means "equal to and the same type". PHP does some conversions if you use `==` that may make values that aren't normally considered equal (for example an empty string and the integer 0) compare as equal.

Comment: @BillKarwin No I don't

Comment: @JoshuaHuber, a default on the PK column wouldn't make the value change during an UPDATE, unless the UPDATE explicitly sets `PK = DEFAULT(PK)`.

Comment: @Arch, can you get access to query logs or binary logs to see what UPDATE statement was ultimately executed? I wonder if there is some extra query rewriting that you don't expect. By the way, you have some pretty bad SQL injection vulnerabilities in your code.

Comment: @BillKarwin, certainly knew it shouldn't update PK unless specified, but still looking for the table's DDL.  Still have no idea which field is the PK -- could it be `academicIDNumber`?  Only the OP can let us know.

Comment: @Arch, or at least `echo $query2` after all variables have been combined into it.